# Angular custom Collapsable directive fails when wrapped around ng-repeat content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I've written a custom *collapsable* directive, that wraps existing views into a container that allows another directive, called *collapser-button*, which essentially tries to hide the container provided by the *collapsable* directive.

**Collapsable**

```
myApp.directive('collapsable', [
    '$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                screenId: '@'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: [
                '$scope',
                function ($scope) {
                    var self = {};

                    self.GetContainer = function (innerHtml) {
                        console.log(innerHtml);
                        var html = "<div id='" + $scope.id + "'>" + innerHtml + "</div>";

                        return html;
                    };

                    self.DoCallBack = function (targetContainerId) {
                        var container = $('#' + targetContainerId);

                        if (container.length > 0) {
                            container.hide("slow");
                        }
                    }

                    // --- //

                    $scope.GetContainer = self.GetContainer;

                    $scope.reference = {
                        doCallBack: self.DoCallBack, // This is a function parameter, DONT use () !!!
                        screenId: $scope.screenId
                    }
                }
            ],
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                var html = $scope.GetContainer($elem.html());

                var linkFn = $compile(html);
                var content = linkFn($scope);

                $elem.html(content);
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**CollapserButton**

```
myApp.directive('collapserButton', [
    '$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                parent: '='
            },
            transclude: true,
            controller: [
                '$scope',
                function ($scope) {
                    var self = {};

                    self.HandleButtonClick = function () {
                        $scope.parent.doCallBack($scope.parent.screenId);
                    }

                    // --- SCOPE --- //

                    $scope.HandleButtonClick = self.HandleButtonClick;
                }],
            link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
                var html = '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="HandleButtonClick()">Collapse</button>';
                var linkFn = $compile(html);
                var content = linkFn($scope);
                $elem.html(content);
            }
        }
}]);
```

**Usage**

```
<collapsable screenid="screen1">
  ...
  ...
  ...
  <collapser-button parent="reference"/>
</collapsable>
```

This works in a static test set-up, now I want to apply it to a real-world usecase:

I have a (single page) view that contains this:

```
<div ng-controller="personController">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 33%" translate>Firstname</th>
                <th style="width: 33%" translate>Firstname2</th>
                <th style="width: 34%" translate>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
                <td>{{ person.Firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.Firstname2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ person.Name }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

That of itself works perfectly, however, if I wrap the collapsable directive around it, the translations and ng-repeater don't work anymore.

You may have noticed that the GetContainer function of 'collapsable' logs the innerHtml to console, for the current set up, that returns this info:

```
<div ng-controller="personController" class="ng-scope">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 33%" translate="" class="ng-scope">Firstname</th>
                <th style="width: 33%" translate="" class="ng-scope">Firstname2</th>
                <th style="width: 34%" translate="" class="ng-scope">Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- ngRepeat: persoon in personen -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how to explain/fix this?

**Update**

This is getting very weird, if I add a non-existent function to my collapsable directive's link, the ng-repeat is rendered correctly:

```
link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
    var html = '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="HandleButtonClick()">Collapse</button>';
    var linkFn = $compile(html);
    var content = linkFn($scope);

    FunctionThatDoesNotExist();

    $elem.html(content);
}
```

As I said, it's rendered correctly now, but that doesn't mean it's fixed, because the collapser-button's parent reference is undefined, although it's correctly defined in the parent collapsible directive.

What I 'think' is that the $compile action isn't working for a full 100%, ie. not all Angular logic is activated.

**Plunkr**

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rQbBP8L8WZ5XhKkTw5WY?p=preview)

If I put the first Blah() (in script.js, line 76) in comment, I get [[object HTMLDivElement]]:

```
link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
    var html = $scope.GetContainer($elem.html());

    var linkFn = $compile(html);
    var content = linkFn($scope);

    //Blah();

    $elem.html(content);
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: I'll see what I can do.

Comment: so, you do it wrong :-) `html` method can access _string_ or function, but you try pass to it html element. You can fix it if change `html` to `append`

Comment: Using prepend and append is a partial fix, there's still some other error but that may be an oversight of some sort, I'll look into it.

Comment: what error you mean?

Comment: for reference to parent scope you should use `$paren` instead of `paren` :-). Also why you do this `$scope.parent.doCallBack` instead of `$scope.parentReference.doCallBack`?

Comment: Could you please provide a little background information on why .html wont work (as an answer)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87977/discussion-between-grundy-and-spikee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few error, and also in most cases with angular you not need in manual manipulate with DOM.
So, first, you use wrong `html` method. [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is a `jqLite` element, that implement a few methods from jQuery, so `element.html` is same as [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/), so, as you can see you can pass to it only *string* or *function*

```
.html( htmlString )
.html( function )
```

but you try pass - html element, and it implicitly convert to string and show *[[object HTMLDivElement]]*

You also not need get content and manual add it, because built-in `transclude` can do it automatically, you should just add template.

also, you not need in `collapserButton` reference to parent, because you can get needed value from parent controller directly.

So, your procedures can be reduced to something like this

```js
  angular.module('ngApp', [])
    .directive('collapsable', [
      '$compile',
      function($compile) {
        return {
          scope: {
            screenId: '@'
          },
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          template: '<div id="{{screenId}}"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
          controller: function($scope) {
            this.DoCallBack = function(targetContainerId) {
              var container = $('#' + targetContainerId);

              if (container.length > 0) {
                container.hide("slow");
              }
            }

            // --- //

            this.screenId = $scope.screenId;
          }
        }
      }
    ])
    .directive('collapserButton', [
      '$compile',
      function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          require: '^?collapsable',
          template: '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="HandleButtonClick()">Collapse</button>',
          link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            $scope.HandleButtonClick = function() {
              $ctrl.DoCallBack($ctrl.screenId);
            }

          }
        }
      }
    ])
    .controller('ngAppController', function($scope) {

      var self = {};

      self.people = [{
        "Firstname": "Jack",
        "Firstname2": "William",
        "Name": "Sparrow",
      }, {
        "Firstname": "Charles",
        "Firstname2": "Foster",
        "Name": "Kane",
      }, {
        "Firstname": "Hannibal",
        "Firstname2": "",
        "Name": "Lecter",
      }];

      // --- //

      $scope.people = self.people;

      $scope.a = 1;
      $scope.b = 2;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div ng-app="ngApp">
  <collapsable screen-id="screen1">
    <div ng-controller="ngAppController">
      <table style="width: 300px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 33%">Firstname</th>
            <th style="width: 33%">Firstname2</th>
            <th style="width: 34%">Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td>{{ person.Firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.Firstname2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.Name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <collapser-button parent-reference="reference"></collapser-button>
  </collapsable>
</div>
```

sample with `ng-hide` and without animations

```js
  angular.module('ngApp', [])
    .directive('collapsable', [
      '$compile',
      function($compile) {
        return {
          scope: {
            screenId: '@'
          },
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          template: '<div id="{{screenId}}" ng-hide="hide"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>',
          controller: function($scope) {
            this.DoCallBack = function(targetContainerId) {
                $scope.hide = true;              
            }

            // --- //

            this.screenId = $scope.screenId;
          }
        }
      }
    ])
    .directive('collapserButton', [
      '$compile',
      function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          require: '^?collapsable',
          template: '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="HandleButtonClick()">Collapse</button>',
          link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            $scope.HandleButtonClick = function() {
              $ctrl.DoCallBack($ctrl.screenId);
            }

          }
        }
      }
    ])
    .controller('ngAppController', function($scope) {

      var self = {};

      self.people = [{
        "Firstname": "Jack",
        "Firstname2": "William",
        "Name": "Sparrow",
      }, {
        "Firstname": "Charles",
        "Firstname2": "Foster",
        "Name": "Kane",
      }, {
        "Firstname": "Hannibal",
        "Firstname2": "",
        "Name": "Lecter",
      }];

      // --- //

      $scope.people = self.people;

      $scope.a = 1;
      $scope.b = 2;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div ng-app="ngApp">
  <collapsable screen-id="screen1">
    <div ng-controller="ngAppController">
      <table style="width: 300px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style="width: 33%">Firstname</th>
            <th style="width: 33%">Firstname2</th>
            <th style="width: 34%">Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td>{{ person.Firstname }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.Firstname2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.Name }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <collapser-button parent-reference="reference"></collapser-button>
  </collapsable>
</div>
```